# Java regex to keep * only at the start or end

Tags: java, regex

User would enter any String character, and the only allowed special character is * which can be placed either at the start or at the end of the string.

For example:

```
*hello*     -> *hello
*h*ello     -> *hello
h*llo*      -> hello*
hello**     -> hello*
**hell**o** -> *hello
```

I like to have a regex to do so.

Comment: did you want to replace `*` inside the string with null value?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans nothing, I'm just stuck.

Comment: you can't be stuck before you started. There's a whole wide world of google for you to learn about javascript and regular expressions. Explore it, then come back once you've done so, tried some things, and learned a little.

Comment: @user2889419 Your question isn't very clear to some users.  It took a while for me to understand your question.  Keeping the title in mind helps me to understand your question.  I believe you'd get better responses if you will include components of your title in yoiur question.  Try adding (or including this text to your question... or something to this effect):  **I would like to have a javex regex to keep only the * at the start of end of a string.*  I believe I understand your question.  This may help others to understand it better.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I had found a solution (as answer), I was just wondering if there is some easier way to do it with regex.

Comment: @user2889419 Try adding an example of your alternate method of doing this, to your question.  This will help the community to see better what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

This one works somehow

```
String s="*he**llo*";//anything
boolean st=(s.startsWith("*"));
boolean et=(s.endsWith("*"));
String ns=s.replaceAll("\\*+","");
ns=(st)?("*"+ns):(et)?(ns+"*"):ns;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below regex would match all the `*` which was not at the start or at the end. Just replace the matched `*` with a null value.

Regex:

```
(?<!^)\*(?!$)
```

Java regex would be,

```
"(?<!^)\\*(?!$)"
```

Replacement string:

```
Empty string
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jZ2eD7/1)

Java code would be,

```
String s="*he*****llo*";
String out=s.replaceAll("(?<!^)\\*(?!$)","");
System.out.println(out);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/1yyztw)

Comment: Dude, it replaces white space for *.

Comment: no, no. see the ideone link bro.

Comment: The new one keeps * at both start and end of the string.

Comment: yes, you don't want to replace `*` if it is present at the start or at the end.

Comment: no buddy, if you look again at on examples, if a string starts with *, rest of the * will be ignored(empty), otherwise it will checks for the end of the string.